# struggling to connect my html form file to my php file

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-5

The below code is used to create a login form page on my website which I'm trying to link to a file called connect.php within the same file.

html file content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Placements4u</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/243/3840/2160" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <form class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" action="connect.php" method="post">
            <div class="mt-3">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3 form-check">
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
              <label class="form-check-label text-white">Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="SignUp" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ms-5">Sign up</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="container-fluid text-black greycol text-center">
      <h5 class="lead">Placements4u</h5>
      <small class="text-black-50">Copyrights Placements4uco. All rights reserved</small>
    </div>
  </footer>
  
</body>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

I have troubleshooted this issue by trying to print the POST superglobal print_r($POST);
and nothing happens  when I press the submit button on the site. when I was expecting an array with keys of input names and values of input data, From this I have assumed their is an issue with the form declaration , however I have looked at a few youtube tutorials and the way they put the post method and action look to be consistent with the way I have done it above. any help would be greatly appreciated, ty for your time.

Comment: `<button type="button" id="SignUp" type="submit"` - there should be only 1 `type` attribute and to submit the form, with no javascript, that should be `type='submit'` ~ it is possible that the former attribute  (button) is being honoured rather than the latter submit so the form won't submit.

Comment: is connect.php the name of the file with this form on it? try <?php if($_POST){ print_r($_POST); }  ?> above this form

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I update your code, I suggest to you use: if else and action="connect.php?action=post" and $_POST not $POST

```
<?php
      if (isset($_GET['action']) == 'post') {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo 'Thank you';
      } else {
      ?>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/243/3840/2160" class="img-fluid">
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <form class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" action="connect.php?action=post" method="post">
                <div class="mt-3">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-3">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-3 form-check">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                  <label class="form-check-label text-white">Remember me</label>
                </div>
                <button name="submit" id="SignUp" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ms-5">Sign up</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Instead of adding `?action=post`, you could simply check the request method: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { ... }`